# MEAN stack authentication issue RxJS not working?

Tags: angular, rxjs, mean-stack, rxjs6

I'm trying to run this MEAN stack authentication code from github: https://github.com/sitepoint-editors/mean-authentication

This is my first time working with MEAN stack specifically.

I have connected the back-end local MongoDB successfully and the front-end Angular compiles and runs as intended. However, when I try to register I get this error:

[Front end Angular site running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyU1t.png)

[Error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwPdY.png)

Here is the line where data is mapped with RxJS. The if(data.token) line is where it crashes due to data being null.

```
const request = (base$).pipe(map((data: TokenResponse) => {
        if (data.token) {
          this.saveToken(data.token);
        }
        return data;
```

Here is the full code for the page:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

export interface UserDetails {
  _id: string;
  email: string;
  name: string;
  exp: number;
  iat: number;
}

interface TokenResponse {
  token: string;
}

export interface TokenPayload {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  name?: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  private token: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}

  private saveToken(token: string): void {
    console.log("hi");
    localStorage.setItem("mean-token", token);
    this.token = token;
  }

  private getToken(): string {
    if (!this.token) {
      this.token = localStorage.getItem("mean-token");
      console.log(this.token);

    }
    return this.token;
  }

  private request(
    method: "post" | "get",
    type: "login" | "register" | "profile",
    user?: TokenPayload
  ): Observable<any> {
    let base$;
    if (method === "post") {
      base$ = this.http.post(`/api/${type}`, user);
      console.log("basepost", base$);
    } else {
      base$ = this.http.get(`/api/${type}`, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.getToken()}` }
      });
    }
    console.log("base", base$);

    const request = (base$).pipe(map((data: TokenResponse) => {
        if (data.token) {
          this.saveToken(data.token);
        }
        return data;
      })
    );

    return request;
  }

  public logout(): void {
    this.token = "";
    window.localStorage.removeItem("mean-token");
    this.router.navigateByUrl("/");
  }

  public getUserDetails(): UserDetails {
    const token = this.getToken();
    let payload;
    if (token) {
      payload = token.split(".")[1];
      payload = window.atob(payload);
      return JSON.parse(payload);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  public isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const user = this.getUserDetails();
    if (user) {
      return user.exp > Date.now() / 1000;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public register(user: TokenPayload): Observable<any> {
    return this.request("post", "register", user);
  }

  public login(user: TokenPayload): Observable<any> {
    return this.request("post", "login", user);
  }

  public profile(): Observable<any> {
    return this.request("get", "profile");
  }
}
```

I would like data to not be null so that it will save the token. Any ideas why I am getting this result of data being null?

This is the guide I found the github through:
https://www.sitepoint.com/mean-stack-angular-angular-cli/

Comment: have you checked in network tab the api call that was made and what it actually returned ? if the data is there maybe you are trying to map it to the wrong interface ?

Comment: I think I figured out the issue, The validators were set on the back end, (users.js in the api models called for a unique email address) but it does not check that it is a unique email on the front end, so if the unique email validator was not met, data would be returned as null.